# What is wrong in the following proof?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space

Consider an arbitrary $d\times d$ pure product state $|a'\rangle|b'\rangle$. Note that, as $|a'\rangle$ and $|b'\rangle$ are pure states one can consider each of them to be a part of complete basis $\{|a\rangle\}$ and $\{|b\rangle\}$ corresponding to first and second party respectively.

Now, consider the measurement basis for both parties to be $\{|i\rangle\}$, where each member of the measurement basis can be written as follows
\begin{align}
\label{e1}
|i\rangle & = \sum_{a}\alpha_{ai}|a\rangle\\
\label{e2}
& = \sum_{b}\beta_{bi}|b\rangle
\end{align}
The normalization condition is given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{a,b}\alpha_{ai}^{*}\beta_{bi}\langle a|b\rangle & = 1
\end{align}

Note that, as $\{|a\rangle\}$ and $\{|b\rangle\}$ forms complete basis we can write the following
\begin{equation}
\label{e6}
\sum_{a,b}|\langle a|b\rangle|^{2}=d
\end{equation}
Using the above two equations we can have the following
\begin{equation}
\label{e7}
\sum_{a,b}\left(\alpha_{ai}^{*}\beta_{bi}-\frac{1}{d}\langle b|a\rangle\right)\langle a|b\rangle=0
\end{equation}

As the above equation is valid for all the members of the measurement basis $\{|i\rangle\}$ we can have the following relationship for all $i$
\begin{equation}
\label{e8}
\alpha_{ai}^{*}\beta_{bi}=\frac{1}{d}\langle b|a\rangle
\end{equation}

I know that the last equation is wrong as I can find counterexamples for $d=2$ when $|a\rangle=|+z\rangle$
$|b\rangle=|+x\rangle$ and $|i\rangle=\cos\theta|+z\rangle+\sin\theta|-z\rangle$. But cannot figure out the fault in the rationale of the above proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation
$$ \sum_{a,b} \left(  \alpha_{ai}^* \beta_{bi} - \frac{1}{d} \left<b|a\right> \right) \left<a|b\right> = 0 \tag{1} $$
(which by the way is correct), even if it holds for every $i$, **does not imply** the following equation:
$$ \alpha_{ai}^* \beta_{bi} = \frac{1}{d} \left<b|a\right> \tag{2} $$

Indeed, you can easily check that in your counterexample eq. $(1)$ is right, but eq. $(2)$ is not. I encourage you to carry out the explicit calculation for this specific case. It will convince you that this implication is wrong.